# Why is the assignment operator private in some libraries? (e.g. RapidJson)

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have encountered some libraries like rapidjson (or wjwwood/serial) where the assignment operator of their more important object is private.
When I try to use the operator on rapidJson:

```
    test.Parse(jsonScheme);
    rapidjson::Document test2;
    test2 = test;
```

... and it produces the following error ...

```
[build] ../main.cpp:45:10: error: ‘rapidjson::GenericDocument<Encoding, Allocator, StackAllocator>& rapidjson::GenericDocument<Encoding, Allocator, StackAllocator>::operator=(const rapidjson::GenericDocument<Encoding, Allocator, StackAllocator>&) [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>; StackAllocator = rapidjson::CrtAllocator]’ is private within this context
[build]    45 |  test2 = test;
[build] In file included from ../main.cpp:7:
[build] .././includes/rapidjson/document.h:2850:22: note: declared private here
[build]  2850 |     GenericDocument& operator=(const GenericDocument&);
```

I see in rapidjson docs that they use the assignment operator with no problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do they assign with `std::move` by any chance?

Comment: are you sure they are not "moving" the object?

Comment: Making operator private without implementation was the old way to mark operator `= delete;`.

Comment: The general reason is to prevent assigning the object  (along with not defining the `operator=()` which causes a link error if `friend`s or members attempt to do an assignment).   Since C++11, marking it `= delete` is preferred.  They may prevent assigning this particular object type, but that doesn't mean they prevent assigning ALL object types.   Presumably there will be something in the documentation that makes it clear why assignment is undesirable for (in this case) `GenericDocument`.

Comment: `rapidjson` 's API is somewhat hard to use if you focus more on user-friendly API other than performance may switch to other API

Comment: Ok thank you for all the comments. I understand that the library wants me to use move semantics instead of the operator =. My c++ level is not that good so i will switch to a more friendly library like nlohmann json. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the question why some libraries don't provide a way to do copy assignment? Or is the question why libraries that don't provide a way to do copy assignment set the assignment operator private (as opposed to not allowing copy assignment some other way)? It seems the answers are addressing the latter question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rapidjson is compatible with pre C++11 compiler, where the =delete directive is not available.

So as @Jarod42 pointed , declaring Copy constructor or copy assignment operator is the old way of prohibiting usage of them. By the way this is stated in some comments,

For example  in reader.h :

```
private:
// Prohibit copy constructor & assignment operator.
GenericReader(const GenericReader&);
GenericReader& operator=(const GenericReader&);
```

Generally, in C++ if the copy operation is not available usually it means that this is an extensive , state full  object (in term of resource usage), that would not make sense to copy.

At least on version v1.1 (last "official" release), most of these classes does not have move constructor neither.
It means that you have to manage them through pointers (smart pointers preferably) if you want to store them in container.

Last point, as you have figured out, nlohmann json API is more "friendly" and intuitive, no comparison. Some features of rapidjson are not available in it nevertheless.